# Graphs vs matrices (when $0$ weight edges are allowed)

Tags: graph-theory, matrices

---

**EDIT:**
I have asked for closing this question, and [posted an improved version on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993167/graphs-vs-matrices-when-0-weight-edges-are-allowed).

I hope this is ok.

---

It is often claimed, including by myself for the last 20 years, that **matrices are equivalent to weighted graphs**, in the following classical sense: any $n\times n$ matrix is equivalent to the graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ and $E = \{(i,j), M_{i,j}\ne 0\}$, with weights $\omega(i,j) = M_{i,j}$. Then, one may translate many graphs concepts and problems into equivalent matrix concepts and problems, and conversely.

This is based on the (generally implicit) assumption that a $0$ weight is equivalent to a non-edge, *i.e.* there cannot be any $0$ weight edge.

However, it seems to me that one may very well **consider graphs where some *existing* edges may have $0$ weight**. In this case, it seems that weighted graphs are no longer strictly equivalent to matrices, or am I missing something? Does it matter?

Note: one may for instance consider a graph modeling friendship between individuals, weighted by the number of times they met in a month, say. Certainly, having not met a friend for a month does not mean you are not friends anymore, right?

Comment: It seems to me you need a particular *kind* of weight function (or a particular interpretation of your weight function) for the matrix to be interesting. For instance, if "product of the edge weights along a path" doesn't translate to something meaningful, then you won't get anything by considering powers of the matrix. For the kind of weight function where this *is* meaningful, zero weight is likely equivalent to a non-edge.

Comment: Note also that there are some situations where a zero weight edge is the same as saying that two vertices can be identified. This happens if for example your weights measure distance, or if your weighs represent some sort of cost (such as resistance in a component of an electric circuit).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in some graph problems there is a distinction between no edge and an edge with weight $0$.  For example, the residual graph for a maximum flow problem requires this distinction. If you want to represent the weighted graph as a matrix, you then need to use a value other than $0$ (perhaps $-1$ or $\infty$) to indicate a missing edge.

Comment: Would $-1$ or $\infty$ be a good choice?  Presumably you still want powers of the matrix to mean something interesting.

Comment: Thanks, we agree that there *is* a difference. But, it remains unclear to me what this says on graph-matrix equivalence, in general. Should a theory of weighted graphs with a forbidden weight value ($0$, $-1$, $\infty$, or other), aka matrix theory, be different from a theory of weighted graphs with the same weight set but without any forbidden value?

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion between a graph and its representation via an adjacency matrix. In the graph only existing *edges* can have a weight, whereas the values in the matrix may encode the absence of edges or the presence of edges *and* their weight simultaneously.
If it is clear from the graph-model that certain edge-weights can't occur, e.g. negative values for didtances, then these impossible weight-values may be used as "sentinel weights" that encode the absence of edges in the graph, that is represented by the matrix.

So the whole confusion is rooted in not differing between a graph and its representation.

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting indeed. However, many people do not see matrices as "representations" of graphs, but the two objects as being strictly equivalent, in the mathematical sense. Some even see graphs as representations of matrices, and I thought it was always ok. I am not so sure anymore, in the specific kind of situations pointed in my question.